# Cannot find PIP in a newly-installed Python3.4 (redhat linux 4) environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Cannot locate PIP in a newly-installed Python3.4 (redhat linux 4) environment.

$ python -V
Python 3.4.1

$ which pip
/usr/bin/which: no pip in (/usr/

$ python -m pip install requests
/usr/local/bin/python3.4: No module named pip

I installed this as an alternate installation and am able to successfully create and run python3.4 scripts. Our other implementation is python 2.3 with no pip.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 the program will be installed as `pip3`.

So you should be able to find it using `which pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this in https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html:

--altinstall: if an alternate installation is requested, the pipX script will not be installed.

Thanks for your response.